# Display a block in Magento Admin Panel

Tags: magento

I am getting error like below

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action::_addContent() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, boolean given,
```

My indexAction code is like below

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        // instantiate the grid container
        $brandBlock = $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('digitech_brandlogo_adminhtml/brandlogo');

        // Add the grid container as the only item on this page
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_addContent($brandBlock)
            ->renderLayout();
    }
```

In this case my Question is What does it mean by "

```
$brandBlock = $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('digitech_brandlogo_adminhtml/brandlogo');
```

" ??

I would like to know about block and layout structure/arrangement for this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late answer may be this one helps someone else
you can use this code, please replace "my_block_name_here" and "activecodeline/developer.phtml" with your block name and template path

```
public function indexAction()
{
//Get current layout state
$this->loadLayout();

$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
'my_block_name_here',
array('template' => 'activecodeline/developer.phtml')
);

$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

$this->renderLayout();
}
```